# Tee command basic behavior

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

I want to simulate the behavior of tee command in a shell script by using while loop and read, or if it’s possible to see the content of the command.

Comment: Show your implementation attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're asking, but for a simplistic example, try this -

```
file=$1             # take an argument that specifies the file to write into
exec 3>&1           # create a dup of stdout
while read line     # now for each line of input
do echo "$line" >&3 # send a copy to the dup of stdout
   echo "$line"     # and a copy into the specified file
done > $file        # this is the file redirection for the loop
```